# Table view reload everything

Tags: xcode3.2

I just wanted the "validate" button to take me back to the home page, but every time I go to the sound library, the themes reload again and again. 
How can I fix this? 
f

```
//FUNCTION THAT GETS THE NAME OF THE SONGS
func gettingSongNames()
{
    let folderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.main.resourcePath!)

    do
    {
        let songPath = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)

        //loop through the found urls
        for song in songPath
        {
            var mySong = song.absoluteString

            if mySong.contains(".mp3")
            {
                let findString = mySong.components(separatedBy: "/")
                mySong = findString[findString.count-1]
                mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: "%20", with: " ")
                mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: ".mp3", with: "")

                songs.append(mySong)
            }

        }


    }

    catch
    {
        print ("ERROR")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What part of the code you posted relates to "validate"?

Comment: @IBAction func pause(_ sender: Any) {
        if audioStuffed == true && audioPlayer.isPlaying
        {
            audioPlayer.pause()
        }
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Backhomepage", sender: self)
     songs = []
    }